# Errors when importing BluetoothChat example

Tags: android-bluetooth

i'm trying to use the BluetoothChat example.
http://jayxie.com/mirrors/android-sdk/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html

But when I import the source from my Android folder into my Eclipse IDE, i get many errors and can't start the application.
I thougt that an example would work without modification?!

I think the code is incomplete, I have no R.java file. As a result of this the 27 errors say "R cannot be resolved to a variable".
But I have no idea where I can get this file.